# How to export the output of gplearn as a sympy expression or some other readable format?

Tags: python, machine-learning, sympy, symbolic-math, gplearn

As much as this may sound like a simple task, I have not encountered a way to do it though the documentation.

After running an arbitrary routine (such as one of these [examples](http://gplearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#example), I get something like

```
>>> print(est_gp)
sqrt(div(add(1.000, sub(div(sqrt(log(0.978)), X0), mul(-0.993, X0))),add(-0.583, 0.592)))
```

How do I (or can I even) convert this to an expression that can be used outside `gplearn`, like a `sympy` expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make it into a SymPy expression with [`sympify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.sympify). This requires providing a dictionary so that things like add, mul, sub, div are interpreted correctly by SymPy:

```
locals = {
    "add": Add,
    "mul": Mul,
    "sub": Lambda((x, y), x - y),
    "div": Lambda((x, y), x/y)
}

sympify('sqrt(div(add(1.000, sub(div(sqrt(log(0.978)), X0), mul(-0.993, X0))), add(-0.583, 0.592)))', locals=locals)
```

This returns a SymPy expression, which prints as

```
sqrt(110.333333333333*X0 + 111.111111111111 + 16.5721799259414*I/X0)
```

The symbol X0 can be accessed as `Symbol("X0")`. Or, which is a more robust approach, you can explicitly say what the symbols are, by creating them and adding them to the dictionary ahead of time.

```
X0 = symbols("X0")
locals = {
    "add": Add,
    "mul": Mul,
    "sub": Lambda((x, y), x - y),
    "div": Lambda((x, y), x/y),
    "X0": X0
}
```

This is needed, for example, to parse I as a symbol "I" rather than "imaginary unit" as SymPy would do by default.

I'm not happy about the evaluation of `sqrt(log(0.978))`. Although `sympify` has option `evaluate=False`, which prevents things like addition, it does not prevent functions with floating point arguments from being evaluated.

Comment: Was searching this for long... +1 for putting it so simply !

Answer (score 7):

Had to alter the accepted answer just a bit to make it work for me.

```
converter = {
    'sub': lambda x, y : x - y,
    'div': lambda x, y : x/y,
    'mul': lambda x, y : x*y,
    'add': lambda x, y : x + y,
    'neg': lambda x    : -x,
    'pow': lambda x, y : x**y
}

sympy.sympify('sqrt(div(add(1.000, sub(div(sqrt(log(0.978)), X0), mul(-0.993, X0))), add(-0.583, 0.592)))', locals=converter)
```